# Change the position of a control programatically

Tags: wpf

I have a xaml code like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Test" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="20" Name="label"/>
    <Button Content="Change" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click"  />
</Grid>
```

How to change the position of the label when I click on the button. ie, change the row and column of the label.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Anand's answer, you can also do it like that :

```
Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);
Grid.SetRow(label, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Grid Controls ColumnProperty and RowProperty like this:

```
label.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
label.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty,0);
```